# Как обеспечить переключение по созданным потокам? Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, многопоточность

Пишу программу, в которой динамически должны создаваться потоки для вычисления пи. Все созданные потоки должны сбрасывать вычисленное пи в осреднитель.

Как я поняла, существование GIL не даёт по-настоящему параллельно исполнять потоки: один поток захватывает GIL, и пока он не отпустит его, другой поток не будет исполняться.

Как передавать исполнение от одного потока другому?
Создаваемые потоки:

```
class PiThread:
    def __init__(self, piaverager):
        self.thread = Thread(target=self.run)
        self.running = True
        self._result_pi = 0
        self.thread.daemon = True

    def run(self):
        while self.running:
            self._result_pi = # здесь вызов функции вычисления пи
            self.pi_averager.calculate_avg_pi(self._result_pi) # обращение к осредняющему объекту

    def pause(self):
        self.running = False

    def resume(self):
        self.running = True

    def get_name(self):
        return self.thread.getName()
```

Класс, котролирующий создание/приостановку потоков:

```
class HeadThread:
    def __init__(self, piaverager):
        self.thread_count = 0
        self.pi = 0
        self.threads = {}
        self.pi_averager = piaverager  # осредняющий объект

    def create_thread(self):
        new_thread = PiThread(self.pi_averager)
        self.threads[new_thread.get_name()] = new_thread
        self.thread_count += 1
        new_thread.thread.start()

    def kill_thread(self, thread_id):
        self.threads[thread_id].pause()
        deleted = self.threads.pop[thread_id]
        self.thread_count -= 1

    def pause_thread(self, thread_id):
        self.threads[thread_id].pause()

    def resume_thread(self, thread_id):
        self.threads[thread_id].resume()

    def get_thread_count(self):
        return self.thread_count
```

Запускаю:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    pi_averager = PiAverager()
    head_core_thread = HeadThread(pi_averager)
    head_core_thread.create_thread()
    head_core_thread.create_thread()
```

Судя по тому, что я получаю после запуска, у работы каждого потока есть таймаут, если после обращения к нему есть ещё какие-то операции в коде, иначе -- постоянно работает последний запущенный поток.

Как заставить поток при передаче вычесленного пи в осреднитель, уступать другому потоку? Попробовала добавить 'time.sleep(5.0)', есть ли другие решения?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по всему `time.sleep()` это решение.